# sub vcl_recv | Magento + Varnish

Tags: reverse-proxy, cache, varnish, magento

I would like to kindly ask someone for help.
I browsed a lot of pages containing Varnish tutorials and sample VCL files,
but I can't find anything related to configurating Varnish for Magento (at least they don't function right).

All manuals I've found thrown a lot of errors during Varnish starting
and it seems thay are suitable for old versions. (Also none of magento modules
PageCache & Varnish Extension don't work for me, because I think Varnish
itself is not working right)

My problem:

1. I get Varnish to cache front-end, but it breaks almost every
functionalities of my forms, payment module, newsletter subscription, etc., etc.

2. I've found out that changing one word in "sub vcl_recv" changes everything
The word is: return(lookup). This is the code of my "sub vcl_recv":

```
sub vcl_recv {

if (req.http.x-forwarded-for) {
    set req.http.X-Forwarded-For =
    req.http.X-Forwarded-For + ", " + client.ip;
} else {
    set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = client.ip;        
    if(server.ip ~ a168_144_38_181){
    set req.backend = b168_144_38_181;
    }
}
if (req.url ~ "^/images") {
    unset req.http.cookie;
} 
    if (req.url ~ "^(/index.php)?/(admin|customer|checkout|add|product_compare|switch|___store|referer|contact|chat|payone|sendfriend|review|api|NOCACHE|post|robots.txt|j2tajaxcheckout|cron.php|varnish)") {
    return(pass);
}
if (req.url ~ "\.(png|gif|jpg|swf|css|js)$") {
 set req.http.user-agent = "Mozilla";
 unset req.http.Https;
 unset req.http.cookie;
 return (lookup);
}
   if (req.request != "GET" &&
   req.request != "HEAD" &&
   req.request != "PUT" &&
   req.request != "POST" &&
   req.request != "TRACE" &&
   req.request != "OPTIONS" &&
   req.request != "DELETE") {
     /* Non-RFC2616 or CONNECT which is weird. */
     return (pipe);
}
#parse accept encoding rulesets to normalize
if (req.http.Accept-Encoding) {
    if (req.url ~ "\.(jpg|png|gif|gz|tgz|bz2|tbz|mp3|ogg)$") {
      # no need of compression
      remove req.http.Accept-Encoding;
    } elsif  (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "gzip") {
        set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "gzip";
    } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "deflate") {
        set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "deflate";
} else {
# unknown algorithm
remove req.http.Accept-Encoding;

remove req.http.Cookie;
remove req.http.X-Pass;
set req.grace = 30s;    

return (lookup);
}
}
```

Can someone kindly help me with setting this up?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Thank you. Thomas

Comment: ////UPDATE//// Forgot to explain: 1. removing "return(lookup)" causes Varnish not-to-cache. Neither miss or hit apperas in "varnishstat", hitratio:0. | 2. leaving "return(lookup)" in vcl_recv causes Varnish to cache like it should, but it breaks lots of functionalities > on-line magento forms(like Contact us) don't send anything, payment module (paypal) throws error, newsletter subscription from home page doesn't function (it refreshes the page after sending e-mail, but nothing appears in admin area in Subscribers.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks that your Varnish is misconfigured

Basically you should pass requests to backend, if they are not GET or HEAD

```
if (req.request != "GET" && req.request != "HEAD") {
return (pass);
}
```

Next, you should review your session management and pass user to backend if some cookie present. Can't say anything about standard Magento cookies, not worked with it yet

Comment: WOW, MAN!!! It seems, you've solved this enormous problem for me!!!(strugling with this for 4 days now). I'm really looking for someone who can help me set-up and tune varnish vcl for Magento. I've browsed a lot of pages but everything related to this theme is outdated and throw many errors. I would like to kindly ask you, if anything comes up to your mind about this theme (Varnish + Magento), could you please share it with me? Maybe I can pay for your support. :)